# Different ruby versions by environment in a Gemfile for rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano3

I'm currently using capistrano 3 to deploy my rails 4 application across several environments.  I want to try and move to ruby 2.1.2 in development (I'm running 2.0.0 in stage / prod).  Is it possible to somehow specify this in a single Gemfile assuming I am using rbenv?

I've tried to following in my `Gemfile` but to no avail:

```
# Gemfile
group :development do
  ruby '2.1.2'
end

group :staging, :production do
  ruby '2.0.0'
end
```

When cap deploy runs on development it aborts due to the perceived version mismatch.

```
Your Ruby version is 2.1.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0
```

Here is the command it is trying to run.

```
cd /home/rails/releases/20140701151045 && ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.2 RAILS_ENV=development RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.2 ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
```

Ideas are much appreciated.  Thanks!

---

**Update**
After input from @toolz and reviewing the bundler code, this just isn't possible (or a good idea).  There are a couple of options:

1. Remove the "ruby" entry from the Gemfile (anything goes)
2. Create separate Gemfiles
3. Create a separate branch for the move to the new Ruby version

I'm going with option #3 and it will solve my problem and seems to be the best practice.

Answer (score 5):

I got it working by doing

`Gemfile`

```
if ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == "development"
  ruby '2.0.0'
elsif ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == "production"
  ruby '2.1.0'
end
```

then assuming you're using rvm you'll have to create a capistrano task to do

`rvm use 2.1.0`

on production

Comment: Thanks for the idea @toolz ... unfortunately no luck.  I added additional information to the original question (maybe this didn't work because of rbenv vs rvm?).

Comment: another alternative would be just to use separate gemfiles, I would think.  Why are you trying to deploy development on your production server anyhow?  Also, I will say I've seen a few similar questions to yours and the general consensus seemed to be this is just bad practice.  I would consider just cloning the project and developing under a separate ruby version.  I can't imagine any circumstance where you would want to do extensive developing using both versions.

Comment: I'm with you -- it isn't possible because I "shouldn't" be doing it. What I was looking to do was simply allow my development / test environment move to the newer version and let stage / prod catch-up when things seem to be working.  I think your suggestion to branch is the better approach.  Thanks for the help!